# Pointer arithmetic or array

Tags: c++

The following is a full example to illustrate my question:

```
#define MAX_LENGTH  32
#define ITEM_COUNT  3

using namespace std;


void doSomething(char ** name, int items)
{

    *name = new char[MAX_LENGTH * items];

    strncpy_s(*name, MAX_LENGTH, "Oracle", 7);
    strncpy_s(*name + MAX_LENGTH, MAX_LENGTH, "Apple", 5);
    strncpy_s(*name + MAX_LENGTH * 2, MAX_LENGTH, "Dell", 4);

}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    char * name = 0;

    doSomething(&name, ITEM_COUNT);

    // Approach 1
    for (int i = 0; i < ITEM_COUNT; i++)
    {
        cout << name + (i * MAX_LENGTH) << endl;
    }

    cout << endl; // blank line

    // Approach 2
    for (int i = 0; i < ITEM_COUNT; i++)
    {
        cout << &name[i * MAX_LENGTH] << endl;
    }

    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

My question is which approach is better to read back the `name` in main function. One way is to treat `name` as an array, another is to do pointer arithmetic.

I like the pointer arithmetic more in this case because that make more sense tome because it is not defined as an array but than it really is same as array. Is there any other consideration which is better?

Comment: You are using name to store an array or array of char, but declared it as a 1D array of char. This is problematic (incorrect usage for pointers)
Since this is C++ recommend using std::vector<std::string> (or std::vector<std::vector<char> >  if you need to deal with raw char). Pass by non-const reference (instead of pointers)

Comment: @Chintan This part is actually given and beyond my control. I have simulated this in the example above but this MFC RFX_Text_Bulk macro which does this thing. I am focusing on how to read the name when its filled up.

Comment: @Chintan It is _not_ an array of array of char. It is a pointer to a pointer. Nothing problematic here.

Comment: @vnp: Its problematic in that the technique is fragile at best.

Comment: @zadane: The two methods are identical. The standard defines `x[y] as *(x+y)`.  Therefore: `name[i * MAX_LENGTH] => *(name + (i * MAX_LENGTH))`. So the best technique is the one that reads the best to your eye (ie it is totally cosmetic).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Avoid the array form of `new`

In my view, code of the form `foo = new T[N];` is right up there with mutable global variables and `goto`s for instantly setting off alarms. In truth, no, it's not quite equal to either global variables or `goto` statements--although both of those set off alarms and need to be examined carefully, there are still situations where either or both *can* be justified. I'm reasonably certain there is *not* a situation where the array form of new can really be justified.

If you're thinking of using `new T[N]`, you probably want a container such as `std::string`, `std::vector` or `std::array`. In this case, given that your contents are of fixed, constant size, `std::array` might make sense. On the other hand, it looks to me like the fixed, constant size is primarily accidental--probably not something that was really intentionally designed, just something that happened because dealing with variable lengths would have added even more ugliness and complexity to code that already has far too much of both.

#### Avoid magic numbers

Right now, you're supplying the lengths of the strings manually when you call `strncpy_s`. This is error-prone (and, in fact, it looks like you probably have an error--you specify the length of `"Oracle"` as 7, when it's actually 6).

#### Avoid C-style strings

Using an `std::vector<std::string>`, this all becomes almost stupidly simple:

```
std::vector<std::string> names { "Oracle", "Apple", "Dell" };

for (auto const &s : names) 
    std::cout << s << "\n";
```

Note that there's no use of either array *or* pointer style notation throughout--both are rendered superfluous.

#### Don't go ab-using the language

The line:

```
using namespace std;
```

...is seen in a lot of beginner's books (and such), but it's an almost spectacularly bad idea in practice. If you insist on doing it at all, at least protect yourself a little bit by putting it in an outer scope, and nesting all your code in a separate scope inside it.

```
int main() { 

    using namespace std;

    {
         // Your code here
    }
}
```

This way if `main` defines something with the same name as something from `namespace std;`, your name will be the one that's found instead of creating an ambiguity.

Two notes:

1. It's generally better to just avoid the problem entirely.
2. This is nearly unique to the `std` namespace--doing the same with other namespaces is much less problematic.

#### Avoid `std::endl`

Most people who use `std::endl` are just using it to write a new-line to a stream. Unfortunately, along with writing a new-line, `std::endl` also *flushes* the stream. This can lead to substantial slow-downs, usually without accomplishing anything useful at all. When you want a new-line, just write a new-line and be done with it.

#### Avoid object-like macros

The preprocessor supports giving symbolic names to values, like:

```
#define MAX_LENGTH  32
#define ITEM_COUNT  3
```

These have a number of problems though, such as the name not being visible during debugging, rendering the code substantially less readable. For this case, you can just use a `const` variable instead:

```
const int max_length = 32;
const int item_count = 3;
```

See previous comment though--in this case, the numbers are artifacts of other shortcomings in the code; when the rest of the code is improved, the need for these will almost certainly disappear.

#### Avoid arbitrary limits

The numbers mentioned in the previous point are problematic for another reason as well: they represent arbitrary limits, in this case on the number and size of items you can store in your collection. Again, if we just use `std::vector<std::string>>`, the need/use for these simply disappears.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. It doesn't quite addressed referencing as pointer or offset but you had a lot of insight on other issues.

Comment: @zadane: I specifically avoided addressing that, because 1) it's not really related to this code (remember, the site is about reviewing code), and 2) people have been arguing about it almost as long as C has existed--I have nothing new to add, and no hope that the question will be resolved.